# How can I create an element and adding class and text to the DOM?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am well aware that this question was asked before, I checked the answears but I couldn't manage to figure it out whats wrong with my code.
I am trying to add a text to a list from a user input by using a click even, so my question is what did I do wrong in here?

HTML

```
<div class="item item2">
   <h3 class="list-title">Title</h3>
   <ul class="scroll-wrap">
      <li class="list-items">Scope</li>
      <li class="list-items">Design</li>
      <li class="list-items">Function</li>
   </ul>
   <input type="text" name="Input" class="add-item"><input class="add-btn" type="submit" value="Add Item">
</div>
```

And JS

```
let button = document.querySelectorAll('.add-btn');
let addItem = document.querySelectorAll('.add-item');
let list = document.querySelectorAll('.scroll-wrap');

button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    let listItem = document.createElement('li');
    listItem.classList.add('list-items');
    listItem.appendChild(document.createTextNode(addItem.value));
    list.appendChild(listItem);
});
```

Comment: querySelectorAll returns an array so you have to loop through each element first!

Comment: `let addItem = document.querySelector('.add-item');`

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please remember this is not a general help forum and there are [policies for what is on topic](/help/on-topic) and [guidelines on what questions should look like](/help/how-to-ask). So please read those, and then update your post to actually have a question in it. Right now all you've done is say there is a problem without saying what it is, and then showing a block of code. Describe what you wanted to do (missing), show how you did that (you got that covered), explain what it does instead (missing) and what debugging you already did (also missing).

Comment: @Kokodoko not technically an array, but a nodelist https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`querySelectorAll()` returns a [nodelist](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) not an element reference. You want `querySelector()`

```
let button = document.querySelector('.add-btn');
let addItem = document.querySelector('.add-item');
let list = document.querySelector('.scroll-wrap');
```

Comment: or `querySelectorAll` with a for loop to attach the event to each element. `[...querySelectorAll('.add-btn')].forEach(el => el.addEventlistener(...))`